# Short circuiting to set variable defaults in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to set variable defaults for a shell script using short circuiting?

Script call 1: `my_script.sh "apple"  "carrot"`

Script call 2: `my_script.sh "apple"`

**my_script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
fruit=$1
vegetable=$2 || "green bean"

# Do something with fruits and vegetables
```

When I do that, it doesn't seem like the default ever gets used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Did you indicate that the script should use a specific shell? I always defaul to use `bash` as so:</strike>

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Nice explanation of the concept [here](http://www.bashguru.com/2009/11/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script.html).

**EDIT:** Okay, I better understand the question now. The original poster wants to set default values if variables are not passed. Nice explanation on setting default variables [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-ksh-if-variable-is-not-defined-set-default-variable/). Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fruit=${1-apple}
vegetable=${2-green bean}

echo $fruit;
echo $vegetable;
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand why that should be there, but I had used it because I saw it in an example script my friend sent me. I guess I should also add that I'm running this in iTerm on OSX, in case that affects how things work.

Comment: @sureshvv The colon can be omitted if you only want to test that a parameter is unset. It's possible that the empty string is a valid value for a parameter, in which case you wouldn't want to replace its value.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the syntax:

```
a=${1:-default}
```